# Android image download for loop concurrent execution exception error

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

Hello I have a basic problem with my code. I want to download all images as Bitmap with URL. flagUris is a arraylist with uris in it. To download that I basically made a for loop but it gives an error. I tried surrounding with try catches but it didnt work. What should I do?

```
private void preInit(){
    Bitmap[] myArray=new Bitmap[100];

    for(int i=0;i<flagUris.size();i++){
         myArray[i]=Glide.with(this).load(flagUris.get(i)).asBitmap().into(100, 100).get();
    }
    initializePage();
}
```

It says that concurrentExecutionException. Should I use mutex locks or is there any easy way to fix the problem? (I tried both with picasso and glide) Thank you

Comment: is the ConcurrentExecutionException on the myArray?

Comment: yes "  myArray[i]=Glide.with(this).load(flagUris.get(i)).asBitmap().into(100, 100).get(); " gives the error.

Comment: the get() functions might be returning simultaneously and trying to write to the myArray array?

Comment: I think it is caused  by for loop. it creates 20 different threads then they asyncronisely modify that variablle

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap[] myArray=new Bitmap[100];
```

Might be concurrently accessed by all the different async threads started by Glide `get()`ting their value.. Try using making a object for locking and locking the array when you use `get()`, perhaps using a `FutureTask` as shown in the documentation [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads) and [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/FutureTarget.html).

```
FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureTarget = Glide.with(this).load(flagUris.get(i)).asBitmap().into(100, 100)
 Bitmap myBitmap = futureTarget.get();
 //Get a lock on the Array, Write to Array, Release Array for others.
```

[Java Synchronized Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) for creating the objects to lock the array